# Haskell vs C performance in a linspace function

Tags: c, performance, haskell

Implementing a `linspace` function, which takes Start, End and optionally Steps as its arguments and outputs a list of evenly distributed (numerical) values with first element being Start and the last being End. Length of resulting list is (Steps + 1). It's similar to MATLAB's `linspace`.

One implementation is in Haskell, the other is in C. Guess who's billion times faster. Need help understanding what is wrong with the Haskell code.

Update for people, who asked some relevant information.
To compile C: `gcc -o linspace linspace.c`
gcc: `12.2.0`
To compile Haskell: `ghc -O2 -o linspace linspace.hs`
ghc: `9.0.2`

For benchmark use `sh`'s `time linspace 0 10 100000`. My results are as follows.
C (test 1):

```
real    0m0.187s
user    0m0.076s
sys 0m0.012s
```

C (test 2):

```
real    0m0.132s
user    0m0.068s
sys 0m0.010s
```

Only two tests for C, because result is consistently within the range of these two.
Haskell:

```
*takes forever*
```

Haskell code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import System.Environment

linspace :: Fractional a => a -> a -> Maybe Int -> [a]
linspace start end maybe = linspace' [] 0
  where
    stepCount =
        case maybe of
            Just i
                | i > 0 -> i
                | otherwise -> errorWithoutStackTrace "Number of steps must be > 0"
            Nothing -> 100
    stepSize = abs $ (end - start) / (fromIntegral stepCount)
    linspace' !acc n
        | n > stepCount = acc
        | otherwise =
            let !el = start + stepSize * (fromIntegral n)
             in linspace' (acc ++ [el]) (n + 1)

main = do
    argv <- getArgs
    let argc = length argv
    if argc /= 2 && argc /= 3
        then errorWithoutStackTrace "linspace <start> <end> [steps]"
        else return ()
    let start = read $ argv !! 0 :: Double
        end = read $ argv !! 1 :: Double
        steps =
            if argc == 3
                then Just $ read (argv !! 2) :: Maybe Int
                else Nothing
    putStrLn . show $ linspace start end steps
```

C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3 && argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: linspace <start> <end> [steps]\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    errno = 0;
    double start, end;
    int steps;
    start = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    if (errno) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    errno = 0;
    end = strtod(argv[2], NULL);
    if (errno) {
        perror(argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    errno = 0;
    if (argc == 4) {
        steps = (int) strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);
        if (errno) {
            perror(argv[3]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else if (steps <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Number of steps must be > 0\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else
        steps = 100;
    
    double stepSize;
    stepSize = fabs((start - end) / steps);
    double *vals;
    vals = malloc(sizeof(double) * (steps + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        vals[i] = start + stepSize * i;
    }
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        if (i == steps)
            printf("%f", vals[i]);
        else
            printf("%f, ", vals[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Don't mind that I'm taking absolute values. Lets say it's not indented to be used with negative values.

Comment: This kind of post is more suitable to https://codereview.stackexchange.com as it asks for open-ended feedback rather than a solution for a specific problem.

Comment: Note that you do not measure the execution of `linspace` function but rather the execution time of the whole process and all its IO operations.

Comment: It is a sort of cruel irony that you allow the C program to be lazy (write results to stdout and forget them), but demand that the Haskell program be strict (it must materialize the entire list all at once before it can do anything with it).

Comment: Show the benchmark too. How did you compile it, with what compiler, etc.

Comment: Generating a list by recursively appending an element as in `acc ++ [el]` is inefficient. This looks like it can be solved using a list comprehension `[ start + stepSize * fromIntegral i | i <- ... ]` which is simpler, shorter, and more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your Haskell code is here:

```hs
linspace' !acc n
    | n > stepCount = acc
    | otherwise =
        let !el = start + stepSize * (fromIntegral n)
         in linspace' (acc ++ [el]) (n + 1)
```

This is an `O(n^2)` algorithm to construct the list because each `acc ++ [e1]` expression requires the entire `acc` list to be traversed before the `[e1]` singleton can be added to the end.

If you delete the definition of `linspace'` and replace the first `linspace` line with:

```hs
linspace start end maybe = [start + fromIntegral n * stepSize | n <- [0..stepCount]]
```

you'll find that the resulting Haskell program is a little more competitive with the C version, maybe around 5 times slower instead of a billion.

Comment: For me it's 3-3.5 times slower. Tried to do dynamic array allocation in C, but that had almost no impact on speed. I guess Haskell's lists are just hopeless for this kind of job.